# How can I add leading whitespace in front of the NSString?

Tags: nsstring, whitespace

I need the String always have length 5...
for example, if

I pass `hello"`, I get `"hello"`
I pass `"xml"`, I get `"  xml"` (two spaces before "xml");
I pass `"i"`, I get `"    i"` (four spaces before "i").

What is the most efficient way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *yourString;//your string
NSMutableString *string;
if([string length]<5){
   NSInteger length = 5-[string length];
     for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        [string appendFormat:@" "];
       }
[yourString appendString:string];

    }
```

//now you can use yourString .it is formatted.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this might help:

```
int maxLength = 5;
NSString *text = @"xml";
NSString *result = [text stringByPaddingToLength:(maxLength-[text length]) withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
```