# How do I add spaces after a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am wanting to add spaces after a string in objective c....so I can perform some padding.

I have viewed the method at this question - [How can I add leading whitespace in front of the NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178332/how-can-i-add-leading-whitespace-in-front-of-the-nsstring/13582126#13582126)

But it only seems to work for spaces in front of a NSString.

Edit: These don't seem to be working, here is some information.

I am performing this inside `- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath` - Where I have an image being displayed also to the right of the text. But my text is too close to the image. I know I can create a UITextView to deal with this, but this then leads to other issues. Hence the spaces at the end of the text being the simplest solution....but this does not seem to work inside a cell.

Comment: `it only seems to work for spaces in front` That's because that's what that user asked. You can't see how to edit that method?

Comment: Hi James, read my updated post.

Comment: I'd think that you would rather want to reposition image or label view instead of hacking some spaces in there.

Comment: What you should be doing is using constraints and not hacking spaces. Your problem will magnify if you start to implement dynamic fonts or adaptive layout. Switch to auto layout

Comment: Do not use spaces to layout UI. It will break. What happens in a RTL language?! This is beyond stupid. Just position the label and properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple technique

```
NSString *yourString = @"Objective-c is easy";    
NSString *spaceString = @"       ";
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",yourString,spaceString];
```

Comment: This is no longer working as of iOS 10 for some reason, very weird.

Answer (score 3):

You can adapt the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178332/how-can-i-add-leading-whitespace-in-front-of-the-nsstring/13582126#13582126) you found very quickly to get the answer you want.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int maxLength = 5;
    NSString *text = @"xml";
    NSLog(@"Text:\"%@\"", text);

    NSString *result = [text stringByPaddingToLength:MAX(maxLength, text.length)
                                          withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Result:\"%@\"", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I've created an SSCCE and added logs to show that this method works.

```
2014-09-07 16:25:06.713 a.out[29685:507] Text:"xml"
2014-09-07 16:25:06.714 a.out[29685:507] Result:"xml  "
```

Comment: This is, IMO, the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
int maxLength = 5;
NSString *text = @"abc";
if (text.length < maxLength) {
    text = [text stringByPaddingToLength:maxLength withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
}
// result: @"abc  "
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
YourString = [YourString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In Swift 5 Just add padding, see the example.

```
let string = "Demo"
let paddingStr = string.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)

print(paddingStr)


//result:-  "Demo     "
```